# MySql Table formatting in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So this PHP Code would print all the table data from my database on a Web-Page.

```
<?php
$hostname = '127.0.0.1:3306';        
$dbname   = 'login'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
$query="SELECT * FROM markers";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table border='2'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td></div>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table></div>";

}
?>
```

But what Essentially it's doing is that. It's not properly formatted.It comes like this.

[image: Unformatted Table]

What I wanted to do Is to bring this table exactly in the center of the web-page, Give it some fancy borders(curvy edges, Great fonts.)

Comment: You're creating a new table for each database row. You need to only create the table (`<table>`) once, and create new rows (`<tr>`) for each row

Comment: open view source or right click and click view source then see where html is broken. and solve it.

Comment: prepare a style sheet, read css styling..use Firebug/chrome developer tool etc ..adjust margin/padding ..border table blah blah!! :)

Comment: Please look into PDO or MySQLI instead of using mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to recreate the table for each row you are outputting, so change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table></div>";

}
```

to

```
echo "<div><table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how can I bring this to exact center of the page using <div> ?

Comment: Erm.. not entirely sure, I don't do too much with HTML and CSS anymore, but you can try setting the width of the div to `100%`, and then set `margin:auto` on the `table` element

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new table for every iteration through rows. Move the `<table>` tags outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table></div>";

}
```

to

```
 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";    
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put table header in the loop because header will be the same all the time. For header you can try this:

```
<table border="1" align="left">
<tr>
<th>Employee ID</th>
<th>Designation ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
</tr>
if(!result)
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
   <tr>
           <td><?php $row[0];?></td>
   </tr>
 } 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Then in the head of the document, use the following code:

```
<style>
table {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

In order to correctly center the table, it is necessary to set a width for it. It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops (the 2nd inside the first),

```
$result = mysqli_query('your sql');
// begin table, only once
echo '<table>';
// use thead for the table header :)
echo '<thead>';
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo '<th>'.$field->name.'</th>';
}
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
// 1st loop, each rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // each rows start with  <tr> / ends with </tr>
    echo '<tr>';
    // 2nd loop, each field
    foreach($row as $field => $value)
    {
        // you can also add class name in each case of your table, to add custom style
        // for each field in your css
        echo '<td class="'.$field.'">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```